insert() or append() when APPENDING a list?
I'm from C and python is new to me. I know that both insert and append can do the same task of appending an element to a list.
// this is just an EXAMPLE
Using append:
x: list[int] = []
total_elements: int = 0

# inserting
for i in range(5):
    x.append(i)
    total_elements += 1

# printing
for element in x:
    print(f"{element} ", end = "")
print(f"\n{total_elements} elements in list")

and using insert:
x: list[int] = []
total_elements: int = 0

# inserting
for i in range(5):
    x.insert(total_elements, i)
    total_elements += 1

# printing
for element in x:
    print(f"{element} ", end = "")
print(f"\n{total_elements} elements in list")

both will output:
0 1 2 3 4 
5 elements in list


Say, my list keeps growing and growing. And say I want to track the number of elements too. insert() can access the index after the last index (for example, with list size of 100, I can do x.insert(total_elements, num).
Which one would be better and efficient in time consumption, insert or append?
EDIT: Sorry if my question was kind of misleading. The linked question is about PREPENDING, not appending. Before posting my question, I had read that question along with the suggested answers, insert(0,item) is bad because it shifts all the pointers in the array. What I want to ask is APPENDING, since I use insert(total_elements, item) to append. I want to track the number of elements too.
Also thank you for pointing out the more readable and efficient printing code using for element in x:

Do you want this [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

How about this one without looping. x: list[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x.insert(4,5)
print(x)

I believe they should have the same behavior, but you should definitely use .append, why would you use .insert?

since you are new to python, you pretty much never loop like this: for i in range(len(x)):, you just do for item in x: print(item)

Opinion based answer: using append feels more pythonic to me. Performance wise, I doubt there's a difference, but the best way to determine that is by running a timing comparison experiment.

And I've just done a timing experiment, and using .append() seems to be trivially faster, but not in every timing run I did. My recommendation would be: use the function that most simply does what you need: if your intent is to append, call append(), only bother with insert() if you need to place the element somewhere else than at the end. In general, it's reasonable to assume that library functions are well optimized for what they do.

@joanis to be honest, python provides many useful modules and methods. It's kind of overwhelming that to achieve one thing you could use 10 ways; unlike in C, most of the time you code a specific way with a specific function to achieve one thing

@juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for showing me the easier way to print things out! appreciate it!

@cutelittlebunny I'm with you on that one! When I jumped into Python a few years ago I found it quite overwhelming how Python does so many things differently than other languages. I ended up taking a weekly exercise Python course and that really helped. Coming from C, C++ and Perl, the Python way of doing things was in many ways just not intuitive for me for a long time.

From python FAQ:

CPython’s lists are really variable-length arrays, not Lisp-style
linked lists. The implementation uses a contiguous array of references
to other objects, and keeps a pointer to this array and the array’s
length in a list head structure.
This makes indexing a list a[i] an operation whose cost is independent
of the size of the list or the value of the index.
When items are appended or inserted, the array of references is
resized. Some cleverness is applied to improve the performance of
appending items repeatedly; when the array must be grown, some extra
space is allocated so the next few times don’t require an actual
resize.

I recommend to read Laurent Luce's article to understand how Python list is implemented and how append() vs insert() work.
Regarding you question:
As you can see below append is faster BUT there are faster ways. The best one In this test is list comprehension.
I didn't used map because map in python3 returns 'map' object which needs to converted to list using list() (and takes the fun out of the test).
Results:
Using list() 0.7724313329672441
Using listc 1.007791625102982
Using Append 1.175513125024736
Using Insert 1.6196119580417871
Using Extend 2.6952341250143945
Using += 2.795624832971953

The code:
import timeit
import inspect

def using_list():
    l = list(range(5000000))

def using_listc():
    l = [i for i in range(5000000)]

def using_append():
    l = []
    for i in range(5000000):
        l.append(i)

def using_insert():
    l = []
    for i in range(5000000):
        l.insert(i,i)

def using_extend():
    l = []
    for i in range(5000000):
        l.extend([i])

def using_add():
    l = []
    for i in range(5000000):
        l += [i]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    using_list_code = inspect.getsource(using_list) + 'using_list()'
    using_listc_code = inspect.getsource(using_listc) + 'using_listc()'
    using_append_code = inspect.getsource(using_append) + 'using_append()'
    using_insert_code = inspect.getsource(using_insert) + 'using_insert()'
    using_extend_code = inspect.getsource(using_extend) + 'using_extend()'
    using_add_code = inspect.getsource(using_add) + 'using_add()'

    number_of_runs = 10

    t = timeit.timeit(stmt=using_list_code, number=number_of_runs)
    print(f'Using list() {t}')
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt=using_listc_code, number=number_of_runs)
    print(f'Using listc {t}')
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt=using_append_code, number=number_of_runs)
    print(f'Using Append {t}')
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt=using_insert_code, number=number_of_runs)
    print(f'Using Insert {t}')
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt=using_extend_code, number=number_of_runs)
    print(f'Using Extend {t}')
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt=using_add_code, number=number_of_runs)
    print(f'Using += {t}')


Thank you for your answer. My goal was not actually append numbers, but a long long list of data. But from your benchmark, it seems .append() is the most effective way. In the future, I'll just use .append() since it's faster and most people call "pythonic" way

Append is more efficient with O(1) as it always adds to the end of the list. Insert will be less efficient with O(n) as it will move around items as it needs to deal with cases of inserting in the middle.
Hope this helped

In general, insert is O(n), but if used only for appending, as in this question, then it is O(1).
